# Make the App Delegate perform an action?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, delegates

My AppDelegate_Phone class has the method `-(void)doSomething`. How can I call that from within a View Controller `viewController`?

I've tried:

`[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] doSomething];`

No luck.

`doSomething not found in protocol`

Edit. The action is being performed, but the Warning persists in XCode. What does the warning mean?

Comment: Whose delegate? The view controller's?

Comment: The app delegate. In a universal app, `AppDelegate_Phone` is the class I'm referring to as the delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast the delegate to your custom delegate class then call the doSomething. Code example is below:

```
MyAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[myAppDelegate doSomething];
```

Comment: Thank you. I did use bbum's version of the code. I prefer compact code in certain cases, over clarity.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is telling you exactly what is wrong (if a bit impenetrable because of the nested expressions);  `-delegate` returns an object that responds to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol, of which your method is not a part of that protocol.

The most straightforward way to solve this is with a typecast:

```
[(AppDelegate_Phone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] doSomething];
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. +1 for compacting to one line.